# Run with terminal in Visual Studio Code in a new window terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, text-editor, rich-text-editor

Is there any way so when I run a program with terminal it will make a new window terminal not using the default terminal in VS Code?

1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Il0.png (Like this for example)
[image: New Window Terminal Instead of VS Code Terminal]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for way to use a different terminal profile in VS Code, and you don't care to open the terminal in a new window, you can try these steps:

1. Open the VS Code Command Palette: `Cmd + Shift + P`
2. Type "Default"
3. Select `Terminal: Select Default Profile`
4. Select the desired terminal profile you want to use

You can then toggle the terminal in VS Code using `` Ctrl + ` `` .